# How to use NumericProperty() in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get a value from the .kv file to the Python file as follows:

Python:

```
class Calc(Widget):    
    def func(self):

        alp = NumericProperty()
        bet = NumericProperty()

        some calculation ... alp + bet
```

Kivy:

```
<Calc>

 alp: alpha.text
 bet: beta.text

 TextInput:
     id: alpha
 TextInput:
     id: beta
```

I have tried different things (e.g. converting the string to float, int, etc) nothing seems to work. I tried using "alp: alpha", and that does not seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

---

Revision 1

Python:

```
class Calc(Widget):    

    alp = NumericProperty()
    bet = NumericProperty()

    def func(self):

        some calculation ... alp + bet
```

Kivy:

```
<Calc>

    alp: alpha.text
    bet: beta.text

    TextInput:
        id: alpha
    TextInput:
        id: beta
```

So, it is still not working - because e.g. alpha.text returns a string to alp = NumericProperty(). As far as I know, ".text" is the only attribute that returns the content of the InputLabel. Any ideas? Thank you.

---

Revision 2

It seems like I have solved the problem by using ObjectProperty().

Python:

```
class Calc(Widget):    
def func(self):

    alp = ObjectProperty('float')
    bet = ObjectProperty('float')

    some calculation ... alp + bet
```

I also applied the filters 'float' but I do not think they are doing anything. Does anyone know how to set up a nice Error Handler if the user inputs other than numeric values?

Answer (score 3):

Kivy properties must be declared at the class level.  Check out this part of the tutorial: http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/properties.html

That means you should have something like

```
class Calc(Widget):

    alp = NumericProperty()
    bet = NumericProperty()

    def func(self):
        some calculation ... alp + bet
```

Comment: OK, I understand the declaration at class level now. However, I am still not getting numeric values from the .kv file (i.e. alp: alpha.text). Any ideas?

Comment: Update your code to show the changes you've made. Also, note that alpha.text is a string, not a number, perhaps you need to convert it.

Comment: That is exactly my point alpha.text is a string, and I do not know how to convert it for NumericProperty() to accept it.

Comment: Convert it to a number, e.g. float(alpha.text). I think there's also an option to limit the input to numbers, or it's easy to implement that manually.

Comment: @inclement: Could you create a new answer?  I've only dabbled a bit with kivy, so I don't think I can provide much more help at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

if your aim is to get input from Text_Input access text attribute and cast them to float or int and add them and display the result, below code should help

```
class Calc(Widget):    
   alp = ObjectProperty()
   bet = ObjectProperty()

   def func(self):          
      #some calculation ... alp + bet
      add = float(self.alp.text)+ float(self.bet.text)
      #print add to cmd prompt
      print(add)
```

this might help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
from kivy.properties import *
```

Comment: delete first 'import',sorry!